# Python: How to row look up data from a dataframe and multiply in another dataframe based on columns match

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, lookup

I have a data-frame df1 which has the following structure

```
A   B   C   D
10  9   9   4
5   4   4   9
5   10  6   4
9   9   9   4
4   7   10  7
9   7   4   8
5   7   8   9
10  4   10  6
```

I have another data-frame df2 as following,

```
name    factor
A   2
B   3
C   4
D   8
```

How do I look up value for A, B, C, D from df2 and multiply with df1 [A, B, C, D] and get df3 such as,

```
A   B   C   D
20  27  36  32
10  12  16  72
10  30  24  32
18  27  36  32
8   21  40  56
18  21  16  64
10  21  32  72
20  12  40  48
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`mul`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.mul.html) for multiple by `Series` created by [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html):

```
df3 = df1.mul(df2.set_index('name')['factor'])
print (df3)
    A   B   C   D
0  20  27  36  32
1  10  12  16  72
2  10  30  24  32
3  18  27  36  32
4   8  21  40  56
5  18  21  16  64
6  10  21  32  72
7  20  12  40  48
```

Detail:

```
print (df2.set_index('name')['factor'])
name
A    2
B    3
C    4
D    8
Name: factor, dtype: int64
```

EDIT:

If some category is missing is possible use `fillna`, thanks [Wen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47717266/python-how-to-row-look-up-data-from-a-dataframe-and-multiply-in-another-datafra#comment82395031_47717303):

```
s = df2.set_index('name').drop('D')['factor']
print (s)
name
A    2
B    3
C    4
Name: factor, dtype: int64

df3 = df1.mul(s).fillna(df1)
print (df3)
      A     B     C    D
0  20.0  27.0  36.0  4.0
1  10.0  12.0  16.0  9.0
2  10.0  30.0  24.0  4.0
3  18.0  27.0  36.0  4.0
4   8.0  21.0  40.0  7.0
5  18.0  21.0  16.0  8.0
6  10.0  21.0  32.0  9.0
7  20.0  12.0  40.0  6.0
```

EDIT1:

If want compare `DataFrame` by `Series`:

```
s = df2.set_index('name')['factor']
print (s)
name
A    2
B    3
C    4
D    8
Name: factor, dtype: int64

df1['A'] = (np.log(df1['A']) * s['A']) ** 3
print (df1)
           A   B   C  D
0  97.664572   9   9  4
1  33.351293   4   4  9
2  33.351293  10   6  4
3  84.862013   9   9  4
4  21.313578   7  10  7
5  84.862013   7   4  8
6  33.351293   7   8  9
7  97.664572   4  10  6
```

And for all columns:

```
df1 = (np.log(df1) * s) ** 3
print (df1)
           A           B           C            D
0  97.664572  286.409295  678.896108  1364.068975
1  33.351293   71.933325  170.508622  5431.168861
2  33.351293  329.617932  368.145163  1364.068975
3  84.862013  286.409295  678.896108  1364.068975
4  21.313578  198.944581  781.316579  3772.578718
5  84.862013  198.944581  170.508622  4603.732789
6  33.351293  198.944581  575.466599  5431.168861
7  97.664572   71.933325  781.316579  2945.161306
```

Comment: what if I have to do some other mathematical operation like Ln(df1[A])*factor(A).

Comment: It is better adding the fillna(df1), at the end :-)

Comment: Can you explain more?

Comment: I have to write complete mathematical equation based on the two values. Suppose df1['A]' columns and say is X[i] and we have corresponding factor values in df2. Now I have to get a calculated column such that = Log(X[i]* correspoding factor from df2)^3    ----how do I do this?

Comment: So much detailed solution. Thanks a lot! @jezrael